# Enable fn keys to not only dim the screen but turn it completely off

Tags: shortcut-keys, screen, brightness

On my [Xiamo Mi Notebook Air 13](https://www.mi.com/global/mibookair/) I can use the fn keys to increase and decrease screen brightness, but never below a minimum percentage.

Is there any way to edit these keys so that they will allow me to reduce screen brightness to 0? I read a lot of different answers to this question but they either address the issue in pre-wayland times or turn the screen back on as soon as I press any key.

Best
Berliny